# Bank ATM machine in Ruby

Tags: ruby, finance

I've made a simple implementation of a bank ATM machine in pure Ruby. I'd like to hear some recommendations to make my code more idiomatic.

#### atm.rb

This is the startup file. I didn't use a class and I'm getting the user input using  `gets.chomp` and a `case` statement for the flow control.

```
require_relative 'account'

account = Account.new

loop do
  puts "What you want to do?\n1- Deposit\n2- Withdraw\n3- Check balance\n4- Check statement\n5- Exit"
  option = gets.chomp
  case option
  when '1'
    puts "How many dollars do you want to deposit?"
    amount = gets.chomp.to_f
    account.deposit(amount)
  when '2'
    puts "How many dollars do you want to withdraw?"
    amount = gets.chomp.to_f
    account.withdraw(amount)
  when '3'
    puts "You have #{account.balance} USD."
  when '4'
    puts account.statement.join("\n")
  when '5'
    break
  else
    "Wrong option. Try again."
  end
end
```

#### account.rb

I used an array to store the transactions. To check the balance, I'm iterating through the array using the `inject` function.

```
require_relative 'transaction'

class Account
  def initialize
    @transactions = []
  end

  def balance
    @transactions.inject(0) { |sum, transaction| sum + transaction.value }
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    add_transaction(amount, :deposit)
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    add_transaction(amount, :withdraw)
  end

  def statement
    @transactions.map { |transaction| transaction.to_s }
  end

  private
  attr_accessor :transactions

  def add_transaction(amount, type)
    @transactions << Transaction.new(amount, type)
  end
end
```

#### transaction.rb

This is the transaction class. I don't know if it's ok to validate the constructor parameters the way I did.

```
class Transaction
  attr_accessor :amount, :type, :timestamp

  def initialize(amount, type)
    raise 'Invalid type' unless POSSIBLE_TYPES.include? type
    @amount = amount
    @type = type
    @timestamp = Time.now.getutc
  end

  def value
    return @amount if type == :deposit
    -@amount
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@timestamp} - #{type} - #{amount} USD"
  end

  private
  POSSIBLE_TYPES = [:deposit, :withdraw]
end
```

I'm aware that I'm not validating the user input type or value, I'm ok with that.

See it running in [**repl.it**](https://repl.it/repls/ReliableUnevenHamadryas).

Comment: By the way: it is really great that you recognized the `Transaction` abstraction. In almost all OO tutorials, bank accounts are used, but almost always it is taught that a transaction should be an *operation* and the balance should be *data*. When you do this, you run into a lot of trouble with synchronization, once you have concurrent access to your bank accounts. By modeling a transaction as *data* and the balance as an *operation* (a *fold* of the transaction log), you side-step a lot of those problems later on. Kudos for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my first review, so please bear with me. I'll start with atm.rb:

```
require_relative 'account'

account = Account.new

loop do
  # This is totally opinion, but I think doing this by joining a string array looks neater.
  # puts "What you want to do?\n1- Deposit\n2- Withdraw\n3- Check balance\n4- Check statement\n5- Exit"
  puts "What you want to do?"
  options = [
    "1- Deposit",
    "2- Withdraw",
    "3- Check balance",
    "4- Check statement",
    "5- Exit"
  ]
  puts options.join("\n")
  # These two lines can be condensed into one
  # option = gets.chomp
  # case option
  case gets.chomp
  when '1'
    puts "How many dollars do you want to deposit?"
    # You could merge these lines into account.deposit(get.chomp.to_f)
    amount = gets.chomp.to_f
    account.deposit(amount)
  when '2'
    puts "How many dollars do you want to withdraw?"
    # You could merge these lines into account.withdraw(get.chomp.to_f)
    amount = gets.chomp.to_f
    account.withdraw(amount)
  when '3'
    puts "You have #{account.balance} USD."
  when '4'
    puts account.statement.join("\n")
  when '5'
    break
  else
    "Wrong option. Try again."
  end
end
```

This is generally fine, just a couple things that I'd prefer for readability. I have larger ideas for structure for the other two files.

For the `Transaction` class, you really don't need the `@type` instance variable if it can only be `:deposit` or `:withdraw`. You can really just make that information be held in the sign of `@amount`. If `@amount > 0`, it's a deposit, and if `@amount < 0` it's a withdraw. So, with that in mind, here's my revised version:

```
class Transaction
  # This was an attr_accessor. These attributes don't need to be editable, only readable.
  attr_reader :amount, :timestamp

  def initialize(amount)
    @amount = amount.to_f
    @timestamp = Time.now.getutc
  end

  def to_s
    # @amount is an instance variable, and so I added the "@" before it
    # You don't really need type here, but if you want it, use the next line:
    type = @amount > 0 ? "deposit" : "withdraw"
    "#{@timestamp} - #{type} - #{@amount} USD"
  end
end
```

And now, we move to the final file, account.rb:

```
require_relative 'transaction'

class Account
  def initialize
    @transactions = []
  end

  def balance
    # With our modifications to Transaction, we can do this more simply
    # @transactions.inject(0) { |sum, transaction| sum + transaction.value }
    @transactions.map(&:amount).sum
  end

  # In the next 2 methods, we don't to pass type anymore.
  # We can also remove the private add_transaction method, because it doesn't really serve any purpose. If you wanted to modify the transaction creation process, you should do it in Transaction#initialize.
  # I've also added optional type handling, for fun

  def deposit(amount)
    # add_transaction(amount, :deposit)
    @transactions << Transaction.new(amount)
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    # add_transaction(amount, :withdraw)
    @transactions << Transaction.new(-amount)
  end

  def statement
    # This can be simplified with the map(&:to_s) syntax
    # @transactions.map { |transaction| transaction.to_s }
    @transactions.map(&:to_s)
    # You may also want to make the call to #join here, instead of in the main loop, because a statement sounds like it should be a string.
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

You could also get rid of the `Transaction#to_s` method and instead modify the `Account#statement` method to be:

```
class Account
  def statement
    @transactions.map do |t|
      type = t.amount > 0 ? "deposit" : "withdraw"
      "#{t.timestamp} - #{type} - #{t.amount} USD"
      # Personally, I like the extra line for readability, but
      # you could also write it as:
      # "#{t.timestamp} - #{t.amount > 0 ? 'deposit' : 'withdraw'} - #{t.amount} USD"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: No problem! If you have any questions about ruby, feel free to ping me in [the ruby chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44914/ruby-sometimes-on-rails)

Comment: I like the way you changed the `Transaction#initialize`. In my implementation I was raising an exception when the argument passed was invalid. Is that the way to go?

Comment: That would also work. By calling `#to_f` on `amount`, it will throw an error for anything that does not respond to the `#to_f` method. For example, if you passed an array, you'd get an error. But anything that can be coerced to be a float will be.

Comment: Really great improvements. I'll note that the only place you have a local variable is in transaction.to_s. The perfectionist in me would extract type to a private method, or nix it altogether.

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys Hmmm... maybe. I feel like since it's only used in one place, it's better to just use a local variable. And if you're looking at that method anyways, I feel like the formatting should be mixed into `Account#statement` instead of `Transaction#to_s`, like it is. Or at least renamed. Really, a `Transaction` can't be coerced into a string, it has to be formatted to be one.

Comment: Yep, agreed. Would be nice to move the display logic out of the transaction object.